# Intellij Idea fails to run TestNG tests

Tags: intellij-idea

Our team tests contain the arquillian tests along with the normal testng tests. Arquillian is only for running it from maven. When I try to run all the unit tests by right clicking on the /test/java folder the arquillian fail's and will cause all the unit tests to fail/ignored. Any work around for this ?

I'm using Intelli J idea Community 2017.3

```
C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\bin\java -ea -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=59149:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Project\Tools\jdk1.8\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Project\Workspace\AcamVectoring\service-addressability\service-addressability-rest\target\test-classes;C:\Project\Workspace\AcamVectoring\service-addressability\service-addressability-rest\target\classes;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\4.3.8.RELEASE\spring-test-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\container\arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1\1.0.0.Final\arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\container\arquillian-container-spi\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-container-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\core\arquillian-core-spi\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-core-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\config\arquillian-config-api\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-config-api-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\config\arquillian-config-impl-base\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-config-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\shrinkwrap-api\1.2.6\shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\descriptors\shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base\2.0.0-alpha-10\shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-10.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\container\arquillian-container-test-spi\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-container-test-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\testenricher\arquillian-testenricher-cdi\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-testenricher-cdi-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-ext\1.7.25\slf4j-ext-1.7.25.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\weld-core\1.1.9.Final\weld-core-1.1.9.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\weld-api\1.1.Final\weld-api-1.1.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\weld\weld-spi\1.1.Final\weld-spi-1.1.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\jsr250-api\1.0\jsr250-api-1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Beta1\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.5\log4j-api-2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.5\log4j-core-2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-web\2.5\log4j-web-2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\jws\jsr181-api\1.0-MR1\jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\enterprise\concurrent\jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-concurrency-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\faces\jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec\2.2.11\jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\interceptor\jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\json\jboss-json-api_1.0_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-json-api_1.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\management\j2ee\jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\resource\jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\rmi\jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec\1.0.4.Final\jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\security\jacc\jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\security\auth\message\jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\jms\jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\servlet\jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\servlet\jstl\jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec\1.1.2.Final\jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec-1.1.2.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\websocket\jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec\1.1.0.Final\jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\xml\bind\jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec\1.0.4.Final\jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec-1.0.4.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\xml\soap\jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec\1.0.3.Final\jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\xml\ws\jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec\2.0.2.Final\jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.2.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-core\3.2.2\metrics-core-3.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-jvm\3.2.2\metrics-jvm-3.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-annotation\3.2.2\metrics-annotation-3.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-servlets\3.2.2\metrics-servlets-3.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-healthchecks\3.2.2\metrics-healthchecks-3.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\dropwizard\metrics\metrics-json\3.2.2\metrics-json-3.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\papertrail\profiler\1.0.2\profiler-1.0.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.1\joda-time-2.9.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\ryantenney\metrics\metrics-spring\3.1.3\metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\testng\testng\6.11\testng-6.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.64\jcommander-1.64.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.6.2\assertj-core-3.6.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\2.7.21\mockito-core-2.7.21.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.6.11\byte-buddy-1.6.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.6.11\byte-buddy-agent-1.6.11.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.5\objenesis-2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava-testlib\21.0\guava-testlib-21.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.0.15\error_prone_annotations-2.0.15.jar;C:\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\3.2.5\cglib-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.2\asm-5.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant\1.9.6\ant-1.9.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.9.6\ant-launcher-1.9.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\testng\arquillian-testng-container\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-testng-container-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\testng\arquillian-testng-core\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-testng-core-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\test\arquillian-test-api\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-test-api-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\core\arquillian-core-api\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-core-api-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\test\arquillian-test-spi\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-test-spi-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\container\arquillian-container-test-api\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-container-test-api-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\core\arquillian-core-impl-base\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-core-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\test\arquillian-test-impl-base\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-test-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\container\arquillian-container-impl-base\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-container-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\descriptors\shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi\2.0.0-alpha-10\shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-10.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\arquillian\container\arquillian-container-test-impl-base\1.1.13.Final\arquillian-container-test-impl-base-1.1.13.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\shrinkwrap-impl-base\1.2.6\shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\shrinkwrap-spi\1.2.6\shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\resolver\shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven\2.2.2\shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\resolver\shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven\2.2.4\shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-2.2.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\resolver\shrinkwrap-resolver-api\2.2.4\shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.2.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\resolver\shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven\2.2.4\shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-2.2.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\shrinkwrap\resolver\shrinkwrap-resolver-spi\2.2.4\shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.2.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\aether\aether-api\1.0.0.v20140518\aether-api-1.0.0.v20140518.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\aether\aether-impl\1.0.0.v20140518\aether-impl-1.0.0.v20140518.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\aether\aether-spi\1.0.0.v20140518\aether-spi-1.0.0.v20140518.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\aether\aether-util\1.0.0.v20140518\aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\aether\aether-connector-basic\1.0.0.v20140518\aether-connector-basic-1.0.0.v20140518.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\aether\aether-transport-wagon\1.0.0.v20140518\aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-aether-provider\3.2.5\maven-aether-provider-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-model\3.2.5\maven-model-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-model-builder\3.2.5\maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-component-annotations\1.5.5\plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-repository-metadata\3.2.5\maven-repository-metadata-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-settings\3.2.5\maven-settings-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-settings-builder\3.2.5\maven-settings-builder-3.2.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-interpolation\1.21\plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\3.0.20\plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-sec-dispatcher\1.3\plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-cipher\1.4\plexus-cipher-1.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-provider-api\2.6\wagon-provider-api-2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-file\2.6\wagon-file-2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-http-lightweight\2.6\wagon-http-lightweight-2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\wagon\wagon-http-shared\2.6\wagon-http-shared-2.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.7.2\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\4.0.2\stringtemplate-4.0.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.3\antlr-runtime-3.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20160810\json-20160810.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-csv\1.3\commons-csv-1.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-json\1.18.4\jersey-json-1.18.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.1\jettison-1.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.2\jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.2\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-jaxrs\1.9.2\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-xc\1.9.2\jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-core\1.18.4\jersey-core-1.18.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\json-simple\json-simple\1.1\json-simple-1.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\sf\dozer\dozer\5.5.1\dozer-5.5.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.1\commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.5\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.5.4\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\io\swagger\swagger-annotations\1.5.9\swagger-annotations-1.5.9.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-client\2.22.2\jersey-client-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\core\jersey-common\2.22.2\jersey-common-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\bundles\repackaged\jersey-guava\2.22.2\jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\osgi-resource-locator\1.0.1\osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-api\2.4.0-b34\hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-utils\2.4.0-b34\hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\aopalliance-repackaged\2.4.0-b34\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\external\javax.inject\2.4.0-b34\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2-locator\2.4.0-b34\hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-multipart\2.22.2\jersey-media-multipart-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\mimepull\mimepull\1.9.6\mimepull-1.9.6.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\media\jersey-media-json-jackson\2.22.2\jersey-media-json-jackson-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\ext\jersey-entity-filtering\2.22.2\jersey-entity-filtering-2.22.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-base\2.5.4\jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider\2.5.4\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.5.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.5.4\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.7.5\jackson-core-2.7.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.7.5\jackson-annotations-2.7.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.7.5\jackson-databind-2.7.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.7.5\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.7.5.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\brsanthu\migbase64\2.2\migbase64-2.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0\ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\rest-assured\2.9.0\rest-assured-2.9.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy\2.4.4\groovy-2.4.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-xml\2.4.4\groovy-xml-2.4.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.1\httpclient-4.5.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\httpcore-4.4.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.1\httpmime-4.5.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\ccil\cowan\tagsoup\tagsoup\1.2.1\tagsoup-1.2.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\json-path\2.9.0\json-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\groovy\groovy-json\2.4.4\groovy-json-2.4.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\rest-assured-common\2.9.0\rest-assured-common-2.9.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\com\jayway\restassured\xml-path\2.9.0\xml-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-jaxrs\3.0.19.Final\resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.19.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\annotation\jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\net\jcip\jcip-annotations\1.0\jcip-annotations-1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.json\1.0.4\javax.json-1.0.4.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\jboss\resteasy\resteasy-spring\3.0.19.Final\resteasy-spring-3.0.19.Final.jar;C:\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.5\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander.jar" org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket59148 @w@C:\Users\usrpao\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Users\usrpao\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:166)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.arquillianBeforeSuite(Arquillian.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:166)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ManagerBuilder.create(ManagerBuilder.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:62)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.Reflections.getObserverMethods(Reflections.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ExtensionImpl.of(ExtensionImpl.java:51)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.createExtensions(ManagerImpl.java:436)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fireProcessing(ManagerImpl.java:370)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:98)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 54 more


Test ignored.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
thread size 10

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Test ignored.



===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 125, Failures: 0, Skips: 125
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 198
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If there are TestNG test, IDEA should suggest "Run -> All Tests" with TestNG type. So Arquillian tests will be ignored.

Comment: That did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a work around for this issue. Even eclipse has the same issue like this as per my colleague.

Create a testng suite file `testng-developer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="developer" verbose="3" annotations="JDK">
    <test name="developer">
        <packages>
          <package name="net.path.*">
              <exclude name="net.path.acceptance.*"/>
          </package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Then follow the following steps.

1. Go to run configurations
2. '+' on top left, choose TestNG
3. choose a name
4. Test kind : Suite
5. Suite: Select the .xml file that you created
6. In Single module selected
7. Use classpath of module: select the module where this config is located
8. run

Now you should be able to run Code coverage/all developer tests using this run configuration.